# select(), poll() or epoll() ? for sysfs attribute

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, epoll, beagleboard

I am working with gpio interrupts. I have a file in "/sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value". I want a notification whenever there is a change in attribute **value**. So how can I achieve this in user-space. As I have already collected information, I can use select(), poll() or epoll(). So which is correct for this application ? Or please suggest me if I can use /proc/irq or something. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found something [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio.txt) that may be of help:

> GPIO signals have paths like /sys/class/gpio/gpio42/ (for GPIO #42)
>   and have the following read/write attributes:
>
> "value" ... reads as either 0 (low) or 1 (high).  If the GPIO
>     is configured as an output, this value may be written;
>     any nonzero value is treated as high.
>
> If the pin can be configured as interrupt-generating interrupt
>     and if it has been configured to generate interrupts (see the
>     description of "edge"), you can poll(2) on that file and
>     poll(2) will return whenever the interrupt was triggered. If
>     you use poll(2), set the events POLLPRI and POLLERR. If you
>     use select(2), set the file descriptor in exceptfds. After
>     poll(2) returns, either lseek(2) to the beginning of the sysfs
>     file and read the new value or close the file and re-open it
>     to read the value.

Although it says it's for "gpio42", I'm guessing this may apply to your case to.  If it doesn't, make a comment in my answer.

Comment: thanks @tony-the-lion, It means I have to poll for edge file or value file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of them.  The point here is that you open the sysfs file for the GPIO line's value (e.g. `/sys/class/gpio/gpio42/value` and then block on it.

Changes in line state are signalled as an exception condition rather than a write (as might be intuitive).

In the case of select:

```
fd_set exceptfds;
int    res;    

FD_ZERO(&exceptfds);
FD_SET(gpioFileDesc, &exceptfds);

res = select(gpioFileDesc+1, 
             NULL,               // readfds - not needed
             NULL,               // writefds - not needed
             &exceptfds,
             NULL);              // timeout (never)

if (res > 0 && FD_ISSET(gpioFileDesc, &exceptfds))
{
     // GPIO line changed
}
```

Comment: Note that not all GPIOs are interrupt-capable. If the GPIO you're working with doesn't support interrupts (and this will depend on the exact CPU/SoC you're using), you will need to read it periodically.

Comment: There are no doubt cases where this is true -  especially when the GPIO line is implemented with an I2C peripheral or audio codec.  However, in that case, you'd never be calling `select()` `pselect()`,  `poll()` or `epoll()` on them.  [`poll()` and its brethren, don't in fact poll at all]

Comment: Hello @Marko Thank you so much for the reply. Can you please give me a sample code for select which you have mentioned above ? actually how I am doing is when I do echo 1 > file_name, then the notification should print. It will be very helpful.

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK I not entirely sure what more you need than that above.  I'm slightly confused why you're talking about writing to the value file in the comment above, yet asked about using `select()` to detect a change in the line/